# Typing a function that maps a property in an object to another property

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to type a function that maps a property in an object to another property.

E.g. the `mapProperty` function can be used as `mapProperty('_id', 'id', { _id: "arst" } )`. The resulting type should be `{ id: string }`.

I have created the function `mapProperty` typed below, but I feel the `as unknown as M` shouldn't be necessary. However, when I'm not using that, I'm getting the following error:

> Type `'T & { [x: string]: T[K]; }'` is not assignable to type `'M'`.
> `'M'` could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to `'T & { [x: string]: T[K]; }'`.

It's also not possible to type the return value as `: { [key: L]: T[K] }`.

What could be a solution?

```js
const mapProperty = <T, K extends keyof T, M, L extends keyof M>(
  from: K,
  to: L,
  obj: T,
): M => {
  const prop = obj[from];
  delete obj[from];
  return ({ ...obj, [to]: prop } as unknown) as M;
};
```

*Edit: (I used the answer of Николай Гольцев with a twist)*

I added a parameter that's a function that maps the value of the mapped property:

```js
const mapProperty = <T, K extends keyof T, L extends string, M = T[K]>(
  obj: T,
  from: K,
  to: L,
  fn?: (x: T[K]) => M,
): Omit<T, K> & { [key in L]: M } => {
  const prop = fn ? fn(obj[from]) : obj[from];
  delete obj[from];
  return { ...obj, [to]: prop } as any;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be typed like this:

```
const mapProperty = <T, K extends keyof T, L extends string>(
  from: K,
  to: L,
  obj: T,
): Omit<T, K> & {
    [key in L]: T[K]
} => {
  const prop = obj[from];
  delete obj[from];
  return { ...obj, [to]: prop } as any;
};

const k = mapProperty('_id', 'id', { _id: "arst", k: true } )
```

Error arise in the return statement because `delete` operator do nothing with type of variable. After delete operation it still will be `T`. Computed property, as I know, always give type `{ [x: string]: T }`.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on next solution:

```js
type Data = { age: 1, name: 'string' }

// Main utility
type Replace<O, P1 extends keyof O, P2 extends string> =
    Pick<O, Exclude<keyof O, P1>>
    & { [P in P2]: O[P1] }


type Result = Replace<Data, 'name', 'surname'>

const mapProperty = <O, P1 extends keyof O, P2 extends string>(obj: O, from: P1, to: P2): Replace<O, P1, P2> => {
    const { [from]: replaced, ...rest } = obj;

    // don't know how to get rid of casting operators
    return {
        ...rest,
        [to]: replaced
    } as unknown as Replace<O, P1, P2>
}

const data: Data = { age: 1, name: 'string' }

const result = mapProperty(data, 'age', 'year')
type Res = keyof typeof result // "year" | "name"
```

It is considered a good practice to not use `delete` operator at all, because it  is slow and has other drawbacks. As an alternative, you can use [Reflect.deleteProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/deleteProperty) instead. I don't know how to get rid `unknown` casting because of computed nature [to].